# html and PHP In PHP php file, PHP code is printed not run

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" value="Delete ALL" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" />
    </form>

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['deleteAll'] )) { 

        include('CommonMethods.php');
        $debug = false;
        $COMMON = new Common($debug); //common methods

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `availability` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `experience` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `major` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `PersonalInfo` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `refrence` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        echo ("DELETED ALL");

    }
?>
```

This is exact code, missing CommonMethdos.php which works. I have tested the php in another place and it does what I need it to do. It was originally part of a class structure, but I do not believe that would effect it here. The goal is to have the user click a button and that button run the code. Its all I need. I will eventually have a few other buttons and some input boxes, but I need to have the code to work.

Currently, the code is spit out just below the buttons. I am compiling on a web server that I know works correctly, so it must be on my end. It is most likely a simple problem that is obvious to anyone, but I don't know html or PHP that well so help would be appreciated.

Edit: I realized my problem was the type on the file, and not the code its self. I still took answers into consideration because Im still new to these languages.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove <?php from the top and place it just before the if statement.You cant write html code inside php tags this way.You either echo them out or put the html code outside the php tags.Please have a look at writing php

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that this page somewhat renders. I get a syntax error from the first `<` before `html>`

Comment: Is the page called `inde.html` or `index.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your code like this:

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['deleteAll'] )) { 

        include('CommonMethods.php');
        $debug = false;
        $COMMON = new Common($debug); //common methods

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `availability` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `experience` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `major` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `PersonalInfo` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `refrence` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        echo ("DELETED ALL");

    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" value="Delete ALL" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your method, and it looked promising, but it still dosn't do what I need. Like what Tyranicangel said in the comment above, running just echos the php out. If you need to see what I mean, I can add a link to the server I'm compiling on. EDIT: I actually just figured out my problem. I miss-named the file i was working in so it wouldn't compile correctly.

Comment: So it works now? Was this answere helpfull?

Comment: Yes, your answer was helpful, helped me realize I had errors elsewhere in another file. Unfortunately i had a silly mistake in this one which was causing my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

remember PHP is not HTML the output is.

```
<HTML> - <?php
</HTML> - ?>
```

so what you can do is

```
<html>
 <html stuff>
 <html stuff>
 <?php
  echo("php stuff");
 ?>
 <html stuff>
 <html stuff>
</html>
```

also I also suggest always using the method="POST" or method="GET" (use post in here)

Comment: Sorry for the word in the php echo I didn't re-read that I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside  marks but also name the file .php

It's also a good idea separate Models (database definitions), from your bussines logic, from your Views (HTML or whatever)  => see MVC pattern

And try a framework :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it made me go back and check and I had put the wrong type on the file. A silly mistake considering the file that u used to build this one is correct. But thanks all the same.

Comment: Please mark this answer as CORRECT if you consider IS THE answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use html code inside php with **EOF**.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['deleteAll'] )) { 

        include('CommonMethods.php');
        $debug = false;
        $COMMON = new Common($debug); //common methods

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `availability` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `experience` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `major` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `PersonalInfo` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `refrence` WHERE 1";
        $COMMON->executeQuery($sql, $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);

        echo ("DELETED ALL");

    }

    echo <<<EOF
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" value="Delete ALL" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;
?>
```